# Laravel Updated Event (Observer): SQLSTATE[22001] Error

Tags: eloquent, observers, laravel-6.2

I'm trying to append the `species`' ID to its name at the event of an *update* through an `observer`, but for some reason it's somewhat getting *looped* hence the **`SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column`** error:

`SpeciesController@update`

```php
    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Species  $species
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Species $species)
    {
        $species->name = $request->name;
        $species->sort = $request->sort;

        $species->save();

        $updatedSpecies = new SpeciesResource($species);

        return response()->json(compact('updatedSpecies'), 200);
    }
```

`SpeciesObserver@updated`

```php
    /**
     * Handle the species "updated" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Species  $species
     * @return void
     */
    public function updated(Species $species)
    {
        $species->name = "$species->name - $species->id";

        $species->save();
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `updated` event is always fired because you're also saving it inside. Use the `updating` event instead.

```php
/**
 * Handle the species "updating" event.
 *
 * @param  \App\Species  $species
 * @return void
 */
public function updating(Species $species)
{
    $species->name = "$species->name - $species->id";
}
```